# Throughput in Informatica decreasing for one partition thread

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have implemented pass-through partitions (3) on the source qualifier based on the where filter condition in the source qualifier query but when Informatica is running the first 2 partition threads seems to be fast and the Throughput Rows/sec keeps increasing but the third thread does the direct opposite. it keeps decreasing. The source is oracle and the target is also oracle. No of rows returned by the partition query is as follows, to increase query performance we are using /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ hint in the select query as well. can Anyone please advise on the above?

4565978 - First_Query

5715700 - Second_Query

12229827 --> Third_Query

Comment: Hint is always hit/miss thing. Now, can you split number 3 into two parts?

Comment: Ask your DBAs for help. Check table fragmentation, check indexes, check data location and access times. Do a test read on some subsets for performance analysis.